# file not found error on MacOS when trying to download images from url placed in column in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos, image, url

I am trying to download all jpg files whose url are placed in an excel sheet in one columns. I am having an error error 53 in mac its 64 bit version. Would changing long variable type to longptr help?
Here is my code

```
`Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
 
Public Function DownloadURLtoFile(sSourceURL As String, _
sLocalFileName As String) As Boolean
 
Debug.Print sSourceURL
Debug.Print sLocalFileName
DownloadURLtoFile = URLDownloadToFile(0&, _
    sSourceURL, sLocalFileName, &H10, 0&) = 0&

End Function

Sub DownLoadFiles()
Dim cell As Range, rngListOfURL As Range, FirstName As String, LastName As String, spacepos As Integer, lastrow As Long
Dim FolderName As String, FolderString As String
FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CANDIDATURE").Range("B2").Value & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CANDIDATURE").Range("A2").Value 'Choose Folder Name
FolderString = CreateFolderinMacOffice(NameFolder:=FolderName)   'Create Folder
FolderString = FolderString & Application.PathSeparator
'Const PTH = FolderString & Application.PathSeparator   'this is your save to location
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CANDIDATURE").Range("C999999").End(xlUp).Row
'Set rngListOfURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database").Range("AL2:AL26")   'amend as appropriate
Set rngListOfURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CANDIDATURE").Range("I2", Range("I" & lastrow)) 'amend as appropriate
Debug.Print rngListOfURL.Address
i = 2
For Each cell In rngListOfURL
LastName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CANDIDATURE").Cells(i, 6).Value
FirstName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CANDIDATURE").Cells(i, 5).Value
spacepos = InStr(1, LastName, " ")
If spacepos <> 0 Then
LastName = Left(LastName, spacepos - 1)
End If
Debug.Print cell.Address
    If DownloadURLtoFile(cell.Value, FolderString & FirstName & "_" & LastName & ".jpg") Then
        cell.Offset(, 3).Value = "Successfully downloaded"
    Else
        cell.Offset(, 3).Value = "Error - no download"
    End If
i = i + 1
Next cell
  
End Sub


Function CreateFolderinMacOffice(NameFolder As String) As String
    'Function to create folder if it not exists in the Microsoft Office Folder
    Dim OfficeFolder As String
    Dim PathToFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    OfficeFolder = MacScript("return POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) as string")
    OfficeFolder = Replace(OfficeFolder, "/Desktop", "") & _
        "Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/"
    'OfficeFolder = "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\"
    PathToFolder = OfficeFolder & NameFolder
    Debug.Print PathToFolder
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(PathToFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = vbNullString Then
        MkDir PathToFolder
        'You can use this msgbox line for testing if you want
        'MsgBox "You find the new folder in this location :" & PathToFolder
    End If
    CreateFolderinMacOffice = PathToFolder
End Function
`
```

My SheetName is "CANDIDATURE" and URL of Images are Placed in Column I (URL of images) of sheet. The Names of the images would be the name in column F (LastName) & Column E (First Name). The images would be placed in a folder which would be named with column B (Person to which task is assigned) and A (Date). I dont have any experience of VBA in Mac so please leave suggestions.

Comment: I highly doubt that urlmon exists on a Mac.

Comment: ohh m so sry i dont have mac can you tell me which lib to use in this case. i would be highly obliged if you send me solution after testing.

Comment: if anybody could help me out? thanks in advance.